# Setting a hot-key to start powershell on windows

Tags: powershell

On my Ubuntu system, I have set up the guake terminal to open after pressing F12.

Can I do a similar thing on Windows, to open up a Powershell session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) to set any key or key combinations to do just about anything.  It's very easy to script for and very powerful.

Comment: I swear people seem to down vote for no reason.